# log4net in Web Application for Azure Storage Blob?

Tags: azure, log4net

I am trying to store application logs in a storage blob of Azure. I can create a container in Azure using the following code:

```csharp
public override void ActivateOptions()
{
    base.ActivateOptions();

    _account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
    _client = _account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    _cloudBlobContainer = _client.GetContainerReference(ContainerName.ToLower());
    _cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();     
}
```

But here issue is unable to create logs or file in blob storage(container) using log4net.

```xml
<log4net>
  <appender name="AzureAppender2" type="log4net.Appender.AzureBlobAppender, log4net.Appender.Azure">
    <param name="ContainerName" value="testcon" />
    <param name="DirectoryName" value="testcon/logs.txt" />
    <param name="ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=testcon;AccountKey="rftgdfgdfgfdg78=="/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="AzureAppender2" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Cleaned up formatting, title, and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this article:
http://www.kongsli.net/2011/08/15/log4net-writing-log-entries-to-azure-table-storage/

Although it is using Table Storage, you should be able to see the flow.

One thing that I have to mention is that you should log your entries only in PAGE type of blob. BLOCK blob is optimized for few writes but multiple reads. If your app is logging in BLOCK blob, your entire app might experience a bottleneck. On the other hand, PAGE type of blob is optimized for R/W operations and is more friendlier to concept of appending to a file so you should be careful on which classes from Azure SDK are you using.

I.e. do not use CloudBlob class, use CloudPageBlob class, which explicitly gives you APIs for working with PAGE blobs.